# Rickshaw Graph - Can not show Hover

Tags: d3.js, rickshaw

Please check attached image 
[image]

The hover popup is not showing correctly.

Here is my css

```
.rickshaw_graph .detail .x_label { display: none }
.rickshaw_graph .detail .item { line-height: 2; padding: 0.5em;background-color: #8b0000 !important;z-index:10000}
.rickshaw_graph .detail .item.active { line-height: 2; padding: 0.5em;background-color: #8b0000 !important;z-index:10000}
.color-me {background-color: #8b0000 !important;z-index:10000}
.detail_swatch { float: right; display: block; width: 10px; height: 10px; margin: 0 4px 0 0 }
.rickshaw_graph .detail .date { color: #a0a0a0 }
```

and here is hover initialization

```
    var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail( {
        graph: graph,

        xFormatter: function(x) {
            return 'Hello World';
        }
    } );
```

I am showing 3 timeseries graphs on page, which updated every few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write/show us some further code because I tried some of your styling code (CSS) and there isn't any error.

Probably you have changed the CSS of rickshaw graph (or its parent) and the HoverDetail doesn't fully render.

Take a look at the HoverDetail [example](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/formatter.html) for styling your "detail" class.

Comment: I already checked that example & based on that modified css for graph. As default styling was not working.  If you see in css, I added z-index, but still its not working.   Let me try to remove some unnecessary info & then I will able to share it

Comment: Yes the z-index doesn't interfere with the code. If you can share it, it will be good. If you can't, I will edit my answer and post a fully working example with your styling colours etc